# Trigger userform based on sum of 4 cells on a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a holiday and sickness planner/tracker in Excel 2010.

Each colleague has a worksheet(holiday form) where you can see all 52 weeks of the year, as they ask for holiday dates 1 is put in the corresponding cell.

I also have 52 separate worksheets which show a week view and it lists all colleagues. This gets its information from each individual colleagues holiday form.

This all works OK, what I need to do now is if the 4 first-aiders are on holiday at the same time it opens a warning user form.

I have tried the worksheet_change_event and calculate event but nothing works.

The code would need to trigger the userform when the sum of 5 `cells(C23:G23) = 0`

The value of each of these cells comes from a function > `4-sum(C9,c10,c16,c18)` and this is copied across the other 4 cells depending on which column they are in from c to g.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far with the `Worksheet_Change` event or `_Calculate` event?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the `Worksheet_Change`.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngCheck As Range
'// Define the range you need to check:
Set rngCheck = Range("C9:G9,C10:G10,C16:G16,C18:G18")

'// Check to see if the Change happens to one of the computation cells
If Intersect(Target, rngCheck) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


Call Your_SubRoutine

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just add some conditional formatting. That can quickly highlight any issues without having to use VBA, useful if a sheet is going to be shared amongst a number of users (they can't all be trusted to allow macros).

Also, I question why you have 52 output sheets? Seems like overkill? How many colleagues need to fit on each sheet? How many will have access to it? Would a month-view suffice? Could you put all colleagues and dates on one annual sheet and then use a filter to see one colleague at a time, or view by department etc?